Can't figure out how to turn on screen from foreground service or receiver without half or more of the functions being deprecated
I have a foreground service that should turn on the screen of the user everytime an update in the database occurs to let the user know, but I can't seem to figure out how to turn on the screen.
So far I have tried to use wakelock, but all needed settings seem to be deprecated. From what I can tell another option would be R.attr.turnScreenOn, but this would require an activity and as I want this to happen without the app opening up itself this doesn't work (unless there is an activity that doesn't open up the app that I missed out on, if there is please let me know).

"I have a foreground service that should turn on the screen of the user everytime an update in the database occurs to let the user know" -- that is not a standard pattern on Android.

This probably shouldn't be a foregrond service.  It should be using push messaging, to prevent having to have a foreground service stick around if getting data from a server.  If it's generating the data locally, it should probably be WorkManager.
